# Adding entries to datastructure are duplicated

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a R-Tree datastructure and i have the following `RNodeLeaf` class:

```
class RNodeLeaf(object):
def __init__(self, entries=[]):
    self._entries = entries

def addEntry(self, e):
    self._entries.append(e)
```

And i want to distribute some data to the nodes i created. consider this piece of code:

```
        nodes = []
        for i in range(8):

            if i % 4 == 0:
                node = RNodeLeaf()
                nodes.append(node)
            node.addEntry(5)

        print(nodes)
        print(nodes[0]._entries)
        print(nodes[1]._entries)
```

So my assumption would be that there were 2 `RNodeLeafs` created which is true, as i printed `print(nodes)` and both of them have 4 elements.
But then after i print `print(nodes[x]._entries)` i was surprised, because they both the same data.

```
[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

So what am i missing and what can be done to fix this error?

Comment: almost certainly this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: and to fix it, change `entries=[]` to `entries=None`, and add `if entries is None: entries = []`

Comment: The `nodes=[]` is the problem, but I’m too lazy to find the source to mark it as a duplicate. It gets evaluated once, so it’s always the same list. Verify with `nodes[0]._entries is nodes[1]._entries`—they are the exact same object in memory, not just equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you make an argument default to `[]`.
Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) signaled as a duplicate.
Basically, the list at the `__init__` line  defined as `[]` is the same everywhere in your code.
As a consequence, a modification of `entries` in a node will be seen in the `entries` attribute of every other node.

So you need to change your `__init__` from:

```
def __init__(self, entries=[]):
    self._entries = entries
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, entries=None):
    if entries is None:
        entries = []
    self._entries = entries
```

**What you need to remember:** never make an argument default to a mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out and get the same result. If you call the **init**() this way, it will work:

```
node = RNodeLeaf(entries=[])
```

I think, it's because every variable is global and public, but I'm not sure.
[You can read about default parameters here.](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) When you call **init**() the first time it creates 'entries' and when you make this: `self._entries = entries` it doesn't create a new object, it just get a pointer to 'entries'. So at `node.addEntry(5)`, it add it to 'entries'. The second node does the same, get a pointer to 'entries' and this is why you get 2 nodes with the same list.